# rt-mailgate not making tickets with fetchmail and procmail

Tags: procmail, request-tracker

I'm trying to use my mail so that any mail sent to support@mydomain.com are turned into tickets by RT4.

The process currently breaks down in the send mail step. My server is running fetchmail. The mail is being found by fetchmail, as my fetchmail.log reports two found.

Thats where it goes downhill. No mail is sent, and no logs generated.

Here is my ~/.fetchmailrc:

```
set daemon 60                                                                                                                  
set invisible                                                                                                                  
set no bouncemail                                                                                                              
set no syslog                                                                                                                  
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail.log                                                                                             
poll 'mydomain.com' protocol IMAP username 'support@mydomain.com' password 'removedforthisexample'                    
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -Y -d %T"
```

which leads to my .procmailrc file:

```
VERBOSE=YES                                                                                                                    
LOGFILE=/home/ubuntu/proclog.log                                                                                               
LOGABSTRACT=YES                                                                                                                
:0                                                                                                                             
* ^Subject:.*Spam:.*                                                                                                           
/home/ubuntu/Rejected/                                                                                                         

:0                                                                                                                             
* ^From:.*(noreply|donotreply|nobody)@.*                                                                                       
/home/ubuntu/Rejected/                                                                                                         

:0                                                                                                                             
* ^To:.*support@mydomain.com.*                                                                                          
|/usr/bin/perl /opt/rt4/bin/rt-mailgate --no-verify-ssl --url http://rt.mydomain.com/ --queue "Support" --action correspond
```

Nothing is being created in my proclog.log file, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The `/usr/bin/perl` part is not supposed to be in the `.procmailrc` file. I don't know if it is going to break anything in your case, but I recommend you remove since it is not supposed to be there. Also look for relevant lines in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log`.

Comment: Can you hit mailgate directly to create a ticket?

Comment: The `/usr/bin/perl` is harmless (provided this is a valid path) but the fact that no log file is being created indicates that Fetchmail is not running Procmail at all (or perhaps Fetchmail is not running!).  How do you invoke it?  Do you get a Fetchmail log?

Comment: `--no-verify-ssl` is not doing anything when you are not connecting to a `https` URL.

Comment: As always, a trailing `.*` on a regular expression is useless.